# Proving limits with epsilon delta

Tags: calculus, limits

While attempting to the prove that a limit is correct, many [resources](http://www.milefoot.com/math/calculus/limits/DeltaEpsilonProofs03.htm) first find delta in terms of epsilon. This step I agree with. But then they say that to complete the proof, one has to "check whether this delta works." But I find this last step redundant. If one first demands that $ |f(x)-L| <\epsilon $ for any $\epsilon >0 $ and then using algebra, manages to find some range centred on the point of interest for any $\epsilon >0 $   , why does one now need to reverse the algebra to complete the proof? Is it kept to formally check whether or not the delta is actually centred around the point of interest ?

Comment: Please use MathJax to write formulas, e.g. `$|f(x)-L|<\epsilon$` to get $|f(x)-L|<\epsilon$.

Comment: I don't see the statement "check whether this delta works" in the linked resource and I don' recall having seen that elsewhere.

Comment: You can write your argument in such a manner than the process of finding $\delta$ will ensure that it works.

Answer (score 2):

It is always a good idea to double check your work. In the case of limits, the challenge is to find a solution of the inequation

$$0<|x-x_0|<\delta\implies |f(x)-L|<\epsilon\tag1$$

for $\delta$. (The solution need not be tight.)

For example, when $f$ is strictly growing (hence invertible)

$$|f(x)-L|<\epsilon\iff f^{-1}(L-\epsilon)<x<f^{-1}(L+\epsilon)$$ and you can take

$$\delta\le\min(x_0-f^{-1}(L-\epsilon),f^{-1}(L+\epsilon)-x_0).$$

But when $f$ is not monotonic or cannot be inverted analytically, the resolution process is more error-prone*. Hence it is good advice to plug the answer back in $(1)$.

---

As said by @md2perpe, the checking work is enough to make a proof.

---

*More precisely, you have to find a lower bound and an upper bound of $f$ in $[x_0-\delta,x_0+\delta]$ as a function of $\delta$, and express that the range fits in $[L-\epsilon,L+\epsilon]$.

Answer (score 1):

To find $\delta$ is "pre-work". In a proof you don't even need to show how you found $\delta$; you only need to show that it works for the given $\epsilon.$

Comment: Yes, but in the proofs I tried, the pre work step was in itself enough to conclude that our delta works for all $\epsilon$ . I concede in cal 1, I've only seen simple examples like say $ f(x)= x^2 $ and we want lim as x approaches 2. Finding $\delta$ results in (4- $\epsilon$ )^0.5 < $|x|$ < (4+$\epsilon$)^0.5 , which shows that a range always exists around 2 for whatever $\epsilon$. So cant we call this pre work proof on it's own?

Comment: So how would you write the proof? And please use MathJax for the whole formula, not just parts of it, e.g. `$(4-\epsilon)^{1/2} < |x| < (4+\epsilon)^{1/2}$` for $(4-\epsilon)^{1/2} < |x| < (4+\epsilon)^{1/2}$.

Comment: I would do the prework to get to  $(4-\epsilon)^{1/2} < |x| < (4+\epsilon)^{1/2}$. Since this is the range of x that satisfies $|f(x)-L|<\epsilon$  and  since  $(4-\epsilon)^{1/2} < 2 $ and  $ (4+\epsilon)^{1/2} >2 $ , there always exists a range around 2 for any $\epsilon > 0 $ such that $|f(x)-L|<\epsilon$. This meets the limit definition so that's it.

Comment: @Sal_99. Could you please write it down as a complete proof?

Comment: Apologies for forgetting to state that the limit we want to prove is correct is 4 when $f(x)=x^2$ approaches 2.  So we start with $ |f(x) - 4| < \epsilon $  , which can be written as $ 4-\epsilon < x^{2} < 4+\epsilon $ , which can be written as $ (4-\epsilon)^{0.5} < |x| < (4+\epsilon)^{0.5} $ . Now this is the range for x for which $|f(x)−4|<\epsilon $. Now  $ (4-\epsilon)^{0.5} <2 $ and $ (4+\epsilon)^{0.5} >2 $ (taking only the relevant case of the absolute value). So there is always a range around 2 such that  $|f(x)−4|<\epsilon $ for any $\epsilon > 0 $

Comment: . I assume $\epsilon <4$. This is okay since  if we can prove this for <4 , we automatically prove for some $\epsilon >4 $

Comment: Doesn't this look similar to the scenario where one finds roots of polynomials by guessing the root magically and then showing that it satisfies the desired equation? While technically correct this is not what one should aim for, rather the root finding process should be such that the verification step is not needed at all.

Comment: @paramanand, do you mean to say that about the method I suggest ? Indeed one can find the limit in such a way that no verification is needed by following proven rules of limits. However I was interested in proving whether or not a limit is correct , with a limit given, using the epsilon delta definition ( such as the examples in the linked resource )

Comment: @Sal_99: well I am saying that you don't  need to verify that $\delta $ works because one can always have a process of finding $\delta $ which guarantees that it works. As far as your approach is concerned it is nothing but solving inequalities and involves the use of square roots in the example. That makes it circular. In general $\delta$ should be made out of field operations on $\epsilon $ and not use the inverse function.

Comment: @paramanad, I'm a bit confused: how does solving the inequality and using square roots make it circular ? I would get it would be circular if one then proceeded to reverse all these steps ( as they do in the resource).

Comment: @Sal_99: the existence of square roots is based on the fact that square is a continuous function and thus you already know that $x^2\to 4$ as $x\to 2$. This makes it circular. If you are finding $\delta$ by solving inequalities then you are missing the point. Definition of limit is not an exercise in algebraic manipulation of inequalities.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/110192/discussion-between-sal-99-and-paramanand-singh).